# Prevent service image download from docker-compose.override file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a 'vanilla' `docker-compose.yml` file for my platform that I'd like to keep without modifying, and I want to make any updates for my solution to my `docker-compose.override.yml` file.

However there is a service in the `docker-compose.yml` file that I don't need (and I appropriately set `scale:0` for it in the `docker-compose.override.yml` file, so it's not started upon `docker-compose up`).

This works, and my service is not started, however the build phase of `docker-compose up` still sees the service defined, and downloads it's image even though I won't use it.

Is there a way to prevent this image from downloading in the docker-compose build phase, by setting it in `docker-compose.override.yml`?
(Because I don't want to modify docker-compose at all).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's possible to completely remove a service in your override file but you can change the image to be basic alpine so the build/download phase is minimal. Using `restart: "no"` also ensures the "removed" service doesn't try to restart

`docker-compose.override.yml`

```
services:
  service_to_remove:
    image: alpine:latest
    restart: "no"
```

Ideally though, you should only have services required in every environment in your main `docker-compose.yml` and your overriding config files adding or modifying services

Comment: That's a great little trick. Further to this a colleague suggested setting image: .  Now, I'm not sure what '.' as the image would be, but seems as though it's smaller than alpine? Please let me know if that's a bad practice, and alpine or some other well-known small image is better.